# Private registry with TLS

Tags: kubernetes, docker-for-mac, cert-manager

Searching 
From [this](https://guide.opencord.org/cord-6.0/prereqs/docker-registry.html) tutorial you can setup a private registry using Helm.

It is stated in the documented:
*Note: Insecure registries can be used for development, POCs or lab trials. You should not use this in production. There are planty of documents online that guide you through secure registry setup.*

Ok, I have searched(and tried) for two days now, and nothing that actually work with openssl and docker-for-mac.

Do you know?

**Update**:
Steps:
1. Installed cert-manager
2. Follow [this](https://docs.cert-manager.io/en/latest/tasks/issuers/setup-ca.html#creating-an-issuer-referencing-the-secret), to create a certificate
3. Create an Ingress:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: registry-tls
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
      - mydomain.dev
  - secretName: ca-key-pair
  rules:
  - host: mydomain.dev
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: mottled-hydra-docker-registry
          servicePort: 5000
        path: /reg
```

4. Added ca.cert to Keychain on mac
5. `docker push mydomain.dev/mycontainer`

Then I get:

```
The push refers to repository [mydomain.dev/reg/mycontainer]
Get https://mydomain.dev/v2/: x509: certificate is valid for ingress.local, not mydomain.dev
```

Note?: 
1. https://mydomain.dev/**v2**/
2. **ingress.local**

```
kubectl get svc
NAME                            TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
kubernetes                      ClusterIP   10.245.0.1       <none>        443/TCP    4d
mottled-hydra-docker-registry   ClusterIP   10.245.190.70    <none>        5000/TCP   5h
```

svc for the registry, generated by the Helm chart(cert-manager):

```
apiVersion: v1                                                                                                                                                                               │
│kind: Service                                                                                                                                                                                │
│metadata:                                                                                                                                                                                    │
│  creationTimestamp: "2019-03-28T12:46:06Z"                                                                                                                                                  │
│  labels:                                                                                                                                                                                    │
│    app: docker-registry                                                                                                                                                                     │
│    chart: docker-registry-1.7.0                                                                                                                                                             │
│    heritage: Tiller                                                                                                                                                                         │
│    release: mottled-hydra                                                                                                                                                                   │
│  name: mottled-hydra-docker-registry                                                                                                                                                        │
│  namespace: default                                                                                                                                                                         │
│  resourceVersion: "692261"                                                                                                                                                                  │
│  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/services/mottled-hydra-docker-registry                                                                                                                │
│  uid: 742fe252-5157-11e9-851d-ba21af21c59c                                                                                                                                                  │
│spec:                                                                                                                                                                                        │
│  clusterIP: 10.245.190.70                                                                                                                                                                   │
│  ports:                                                                                                                                                                                     │
│  - name: registry                                                                                                                                                                           │
│    port: 5000                                                                                                                                                                               │
│    protocol: TCP                                                                                                                                                                            │
│    targetPort: 5000                                                                                                                                                                         │
│  selector:                                                                                                                                                                                  │
│    app: docker-registry                                                                                                                                                                     │
│    release: mottled-hydra                                                                                                                                                                   │
│  sessionAffinity: None                                                                                                                                                                      │
│  type: ClusterIP                                                                                                                                                                            │
│status:                                                                                                                                                                                      │
│  loadBalancer: {}
```

Comment: How are you exposing your registry?

Comment: Thanks, I will be back in 30 min. with a more in depth description. But in short; 1. openssl generate a certificate on mac, 2. Register the certificate on mac by double click for keychains. 2. Add secret and cert-manager.

Comment: You simply want to tls secure your registry? Do you have a public domain for it? Once your'e back pls post your service and ingress yaml files.

Comment: Yes I have a public domain, and it is working following: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-nginx-ingress-with-cert-manager-on-digitalocean-kubernetes

Comment: But using openssl and all with docker is giving a certificate error, I cant remember - will poste as soon I am at a computer

Comment: Any luck with the yaml files? My guess is that you'll need to use a tls line in your ingress to secure it

Comment: Thanks, I just updated and added the yaml for the registry service. I now suspect it to be a namespace issue - looking into to that at the moment

Comment: But also something with the certificate ingress.local

Comment: Did you create the Certificate yaml for the `*.mydomain.dev` domain? Can you add `kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"` to your ingress annotations?

Comment: From my "new" understanding, using kubernetes.io/tls-acme is when you want to automate all the Let's Encrypt issuing. But I want to just use my own certificates/key pairs. So I guess, in theory I could skip all the CA stuff, and just use a key pairs between docker <--> registry to force the registry to only support docker users that comes in with this key pair. Hope I am not totally off here :-)

Comment: And it looks like using the cert-manager, it enables me to just distribute the public key to a k8s docker registry.

Comment: You're right about the annotation, if you don't want to automate it, keep it out. The error that says the cert is not valid for your domain is the main issue here, did you make the certificate for your wildcard domain?

Comment: I an getting convinced that it is a Google service account. I created this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55416886/authentication-methods-using-a-json-key-file-unauthorized-gcr-login-failed